# Illegal mix of collations MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Hi have an illegal mix of collations when I add an user to a wordpress plugin (wishlist member).

I try to fix it in the database with this command :

```
ALTER TABLE geBAxDrdwlm_contentlevels CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This work on local but not on the server, here is the error I get in thte server :

```
COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

Comment: You might also want to tell us the versions of your local and production MySQL instances, as this could be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong character set - for character set `utf8` the collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` and for character set `utf8mb4` the collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Use the proper character set and collation combination

```
ALTER TABLE geBAxDrdwlm_contentlevels CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Same thing, this is strange :/

Comment: You mean `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is invalid for `utf8mb4` ?